# Firefox ignoring one animation in comma-separated declaration

Tags: css, firefox, css-animations

Firefox is ignoring the declaration for the first animation (`cursorfadein`), while showing the animations that handle the moving and fading out just fine. I've tried using units like `0s` and `0ms`Code below.

```
@-moz-keyframes cursorfadein {
    0% { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}
@-moz-keyframes cursormover {
    0% {
        top: 300px;
        right: 90px;
    }
    50%, 60% {
        top: 204px;
        right: 234px;
    }
    100% {
        top: 300px;
        right: 290px;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes cursorhider {
    0% { opacity: 1; }
    100% { opacity: 0; }
}
.cursor {
    position: absolute;
    background: url(https://cdn.mediacru.sh/A/AhRlh9cYN5sf.png) no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    display: block;
    height: 20px;
    width: 20px;
    -webkit-animation: cursorfadein 3s ease 0s, cursormover 3s ease-in-out 2s both, cursorhider 1s linear 6s both;
    -moz-animation: cursorfadein 3s ease 0s, cursormover 3s ease-in-out 2s both, cursorhider 1s linear 6s both;
    animation: cursorfadein 3s ease 0s, cursormovein 3s ease-in-out 2s both, cursorhider 1s linear 6s both;
}
```

I have the -webkit- and non-prefixed @keyframes as well (included in the Codepen), just wanted to be brief here on SO

Codepen [here](http://codepen.io/SammyJ/pen/NPNJvR).

Comment: typo: cursormovin instead of cursormover.